# Showing Specific List View for community users

Tags: community, list-view

Although this might be a similar (or same) questions to what others have posted, i am still confused on some parts.

I have created a community page (digital experience > sites). I am adding a group of users from my org by giving them the "customer community login" license, through which they will be able to login and see their cases, orders, etc.

Now, since the standard list view in community pages is limited to 4 columns, I am not satisfied with the amount of info that a portal user is able to see (plus, my main point: sorting the list is not so easy as the list I sort in my org doesn't reflect or flows through the portal (eg: sorting cases and order by created date.)

What I am confused on :

1. Can I make all the list views in my org to "share with: all internal users"
2. Make only the list view I want to share with portal users as " share with : All customer portal users" .

This way, the full list view is displayed. They have more columns. And can sort the list.

BIG QUESTION : is this a good approach?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to clarify.  Have you tried setting the list sharing?  Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: I have done the list sharing. But making the list view sharing to "share with: all customer portal users" does not make it visible in the portal. Making it shared with "anyone can see this list view" makes it visible. So, i have made all other list views to "All internal users" and the portal list to "anyone can see it" . It is working as i expect but might not be the best approach.